Does a finite-dimensional algebra have the same length as a regular module when considered as a left module and as a right module?
Let $A$ be a finite-dimensional algebra over a field $k$. Naturally, $A$ can be considered as a left $A-module$ and as a right $A-module$.
So the question arises:
Does a finite-dimensional algebra $A$ have the same length as a regular module when considered as a left module and as a right module? In other words, do we always have
$$l(_{A}A)  =  l(A_{A})\ \ ,$$
where $l(_{A}A)$ and $l(A_{A})$ denote the length of $A$ as a left module and as a right module, respectively?

Consider the algebra
$$A=\begin{pmatrix}k&k&k\\k&k&k\\0&0&k\end{pmatrix}.$$
Then as a left $A$-module, there is a decomposition:
$$A=\begin{pmatrix}k\\k\\0\end{pmatrix}\oplus \begin{pmatrix}k\\k\\0\end{pmatrix}\oplus \begin{pmatrix}k\\k\\k\end{pmatrix},$$
where the first two modules are simple, and the last module has length two:
$$0\subsetneq \begin{pmatrix}k\\k\\0\end{pmatrix}\subsetneq \begin{pmatrix}k\\k\\k\end{pmatrix}.$$
Thus, in total, the left $A$-module $A$ has length $4$. On the other hand, as a right $A$-module, $A$ has a decomposition
$$A=(k,k,k)\oplus(k,k,k)\oplus(0,0,k).$$
Here, the first two modules have length two:
$$0\subsetneq (0,0,k)\subsetneq (k,k,k).$$
Thus, in total, the right $A$-module $A$ has length $5$.

Wow! Beautiful answer, thank you very much!

Another one which is in the same vein, but maybe the simple modules are faster to spot, is $\begin{bmatrix}\mathbb C& \mathbb H\0&\mathbb H\end{bmatrix}$. They're both "triangular matrix rings."
